# How I debug content in many file using Ansible

Tags: file, ansible, yaml

I want to use content in .txt file and I tried to debug content using following code.

```
  - name: Find .txt files
    find:
      paths: "{{output_path}}"
      patterns: '*.txt,'
    register: file_path

  - name: Show content
    debug:
      msg: "{{lookup('file', item.path)}}"
    with_items: "{{file_path.files}}"
```

But I got this error.

```
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/path/file.txt' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

TASK [Show content] ******************************************************

fatal: [10.0.2.40]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred 
while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, 
original message: could not locate file in lookup: /path/file.txt"}
```

How I fix this error?

Comment: Lookup works on controller only. Use [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#ansible-builtin-slurp-slurps-a-file-from-remote-nodes) or [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-builtin-fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) to get the file from the remote host.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your `playbook`, except that you have a comma inside the `find` pattern (this might be just a typo, but you should check it out) if you are running this `playbook` locally. In the case that you are running this `playbook` on a remote server, you should try to use a different module like `slurp` or `fetch`.

`slurp` works great if you need to keep the contents of the `txt` in memory to use it on another task. Bear in mind that ansible will encode the `slurp` module's output in `base64`, so you should decode it first when you want to use it. [From the module example page:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html).`

```yaml
- name: Find out what the remote machine's mounts are
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /proc/mounts
  register: mounts

- name: Print returned information
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ mounts['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

You can verify what I am saying with the following example:

I tried replicating your situation locally. On a temporary folder, I run the following command to populate it with many `.txt` files:

```sh
echo {001..099} > file_{001..099}.txt
```

Then I wrote the same `playbook` that you provided:

```yaml
#
# show_contents.yml
#
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Find .txt files
      find:
        paths: "{{ output_files }}"
        patterns: "*.txt"
      register: file_path

    - name: Debug the file_path variable
      debug:
        var: file_path

    - name: Get the contents of the files using debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', item.path ) }}"
      loop: "{{ file_path.files }}"
```

If you run this `playbook`, passing the appropriate `output_files` variable with `--extra-vars`, the `playbook` works fine.

```sh
ansible-playbook show_contents.yml --extra-vars "output_files=/tmp/ansible"
```

You'll see that the `playbook` runs without an issue. Try using this example to figure out what you are trying to achieve. And then modify the `playbook` to use some of the previously mentioned `modules` when working with remote servers.